# Finding a path to calculate a tangent space in a matrix manifold

Tags: matrices, smooth-manifolds, matrix-rank

Let $A = \begin{bmatrix} A_{11} & A_{12} \\ A_{21} & A_{22} \end{bmatrix}$ be in $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ such that $\mathrm{rank}(A) = k$ and $A_{11}$ is a $k \times k$ invertible matrix.

Is there a (nonconstant) path $\gamma : (-1,1) \to \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ such that $\gamma(t)$ has rank $k$ for each $t$ in $(-1,1)$ and $\gamma(0) = A$?

I'm trying to find the tangent space at $A$ of the submanifold of rank $k$ matrices in $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$.

Comment: I think we're missing elements here. $\gamma(t)=A$ for all $t \in (-1,+1)$ works?

Comment: @Jean-PierreMerx You're right. The submanifold of rank $k$ matrices has dimension $(m-k)(n-k)$, so we enough paths to generate the tangent space of the same dimension. How should I reword the question?

Comment: I added "nonconstant" to the question.

Comment: If $X$ is a matrix of rank $k$, then $t \mapsto e^{tX} - I$ is such a path through the space of $A$ such that rank$(A) \leq k$.

Comment: This will only work for the case $m=n$, though.